# Conditionally rerender react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Let's see we have a `Form` component:

```
//...
const formsReducer = (forms = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CREATE_FORM" : {
      const { id, inputIds } = action;

      return {
        ...forms,
        [id]: inputIds.reduce((inputs, inputId) => {

          inputs[inputId] = "";

          return inputs;
        }, {})
      };
    };
    default : return forms
  };
};
//...
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const createForm = (id, inputIds) => ({
  type: "CREATE_FORM",
  id,
  inputIds
})

const Form = ({
    id,
    inputs,
    onSubmit,

    createForm,

    getState //!!
}) => {

  useEffect(() => {
      createForm(id, inputs.map(({ inputId }) => inputId))
  }, []);

  submit = () => {
    const inputValues = getState().forms[id];

    onSubmit(inputValues);
  };

  return (
    <div className="form">
      {inputs.map(props => <Input {...props} />)
      <button onClick={submit}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  )

};

const mapDispatchToProps = { createForm };

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Form);
```

Where the inputs are dispatching their values into the redux store. What I want to earn is not to unnecessarily re-render the `Form` component, but it should know the inputs values on submit. The above example with `getState` could be a good solution, but first, I don't know any possible solutions to implement it.

Secondly, it would get the whole redux state (which is not good for performance). What I was thought about is to dispatch an event with the submit button (for an example it sets `state.forms[formId].submit = true`, and listen to it, and the inputs values with the `Form` through `mapStateToProps`, but set a `React.memo` on it, and pass `shouldComponentUpdate = (prev, next) => prev.submit !== next.submit` as a second argument.

This way `Form` will just update, if it gets the "green light", and if `submit` is true, it just calls `onSubmit` with the input values from `mapStateToProps`. And the third solution in my mind is to make the button as a component, and listen to every change in the form. Rerendering a button is not as expensive as rerendering the whole form every time. What would be the most efficient solution for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be storing form state in redux unless you are using redux form or need to access that data somewhere else in the app. Component state is a much better solution for something like form state. You will have to rerender parts of the form if you want the updates to the field to show in the screen. Using component state means you only re-render the form, not the whole app. This should be fine performance wise. Once you have the form data set and validated, then fire off a dispatch function on submit and tie everything back into redux.

Comment: Just because you are using redux doesn't mean you have to use it everywhere.  Keeping component-specific state in local state means less clutter from unnecessary action and reducer boilerplate and its easier to reason about component state since there is less indirection. I love redux, but only use it where it's helpful.

Comment: And what if the form needs to process the data it gets as `inputs` in an "expensive" way? The above snippet is just a demonstration, but the purpose of this form is to make is as flexible as it can, with passing just a few properties to it, but it means that the `Form` needs to calculate, and construct the working of the inputs. Before this question I created the form with react state, but as it needed to calculate the properties of `Input` every time an input change happened, it became a bit slow. I was thought about calculating the input props on mount, and store it in react state,

Comment: to not calculate the inputs props every time it changes, but as I read about it, it doesn't seems like an advisable way to solve this problem.

Comment: If your question differs from the one you have asked then please update your question with the relevant code as I can only refer to what you have posted.